# Draw locations by passing a different current location and the location around it (POIs) wikitude?

Tags: javascript, ios, augmented-reality, markers, wikitude

I've implemented Wikitude ARView and my client having some issues after loading POIs around his location (wrong direction and altitudes for markers). So, I tried hard coding his current location and passed POIs around his location to Wikitude ARView. But it didn't work as it didn't display any markers on the ARView.

1.) I just need to know is this possible in Wikitude ARView? and what is the mechanism exactly Wikitude using while drawing markers on the view? (i.e. Do they internally track user location? and etc)

2.) If Yes, Please I need some guidance of documentation (if any) or anything to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

1) On iOS, the Wikitude SDK uses the CLLocationManager class to get the current location. On Android, you have to impl. your own location handling (sample code is provided with the SDK Example application). 
Both native SDKs however allow you to inject a **custom location** which is then used as reference for the Architect World.
The SDK also provides a RelativeLocation (JS) which may also be helpful for your impl.

2) As mentioned before, have a look at the SDK Example Application that is provided with the SDK. The SDK package also contains a documentations which covers the native SDK as well as the JavaScript API.